# Scheduled agents not being added

Tags: sitecore, agents

I am developing a Sitecore solution in which I have implemented an agent and registered it in an include configuration file as such:

```
<agent name="Start customer data import job"
       type="My.Namespace.MyJob" 
       method="DoSomething" interval="00:02:00" />
```

I can see in hostname/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx that the include file is correctly applied and tha the agent is next to the existing agents.

For now, the job simply logs `INFO` (I have given bogus namespace, class and method names, but the actual configuration is correct):

using Sitecore.Diagnostics;

```
namespace My.Namespace
{
    public class MyJob
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Log.Info("My custom job has started.", this);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I could see that the log statements were not written at all. Logging level indeed allows for `INFO` to be logged. After looking around for a while, I could see that the scheduler never logs that it is adding the agents. From what I can find on google, the log should include statements like `Adding agent: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent`, but it doesn't.

It seems that the scheduler is not running, but why?

I am using Sitecore 8.1 Update 3 (rev. 160519).

**Edit:** The job is being run on our test server, so it is definitely something wrong with my installation of Sitecore.

Comment: can you check using http://hostname/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx if your agent appear

Comment: Yes, it is there. I have updated the question.

Comment: can you also check value of <frequency>
in <scheduling> section ?

Comment: It looks like this: ``<frequency>00:00:05</frequency>``

Comment: Are you sure the jobs aren't starting? (decrease the interval on your job for testing and use a debugger). Just asking to make sure the issue is in the scheduler and not in the logging...

Comment: can you add to your question your method from the agent_

Comment: @SitecoreClimber There you go, though it doesn't really give anything.

Comment: @Gatogordo I am sure. I have tried debugging but the breakpoint is never hit. I can see that the job is being run on the test server, so it is definitely something wrong with my installation (added to the question).

Comment: For me is working fine: please see http://picpaste.com/Capture-zY6gWQym.PNG . Something is wrong with your agent definition . Please add 1 sec on frequency and 5 sec to time interval for test.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber I disagree. As I wrote, the same job is running fine on a different environment, so I am almost completely sure the scheduler is somehow not starting. The question is why.

Comment: If it is running fine on a different environment, what are the differences? Can you compare the configs?

Comment: Or maybe it's time to ask Sitecore Support - send them a support package  from your faulty environment.

Comment: @Gatogordo I was able to pinpoint the difference between the environments as you suggested. It turned out that an old configuration file deleted the scheduler initialization pipeline, causing the scheduler to never  be initialized. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an old configuration file lying around in the `Include` folder, which had the following patch:

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeScheduler, Sitecore.Kernel">
          <patch:delete />
        </processor>
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This patch makes sure that the scheduler is never initialized and the agents are never run. Deleting the configuration file solved the problem.